# 18.04.1 LTS systemd-network not applying [RoutingPolicyRule]

Tags: networking, 18.04, systemd, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have a server instance with two interfaces, and I have created a rule to ensure traffic that comes in ens160 goes out ens160 despite matching the default route for ens192.

The routes and rules work as desired when created by hand using `ip`, when applied by netplan `netplan apply`, but not when systemd-networkd is restarted with the netplan-generated config files. Specifically, the rule is not applied.

netplan.yaml:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.238/26
            - 192.168.1.240/26
            - 192.168.1.241/26
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.1.193
            routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.1.193
              table: 200
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.1.192/26
              table: 200
        ens192:
            addresses:
            - 10.125.210.38/23
            dhcp4: false
    version: 2
```

/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens160.network:

```
[Match]
Name=ens160

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.238/26
Address=192.168.1.240/26
Address=192.168.1.241/26
Gateway=192.168.1.193

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=192.168.1.193
Table=200

[RoutingPolicyRule]
From=192.168.1.192/26
Table=200
```

ip route list:

```
default via 192.168.1.193 dev ens160 proto static
10.125.210.0/23 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.125.210.38
192.168.1.192/26 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.238
```

ip route list table 200:

```
default via 192.168.1.193 dev ens160 proto static
```

After `netplan apply`, `ip rule list` (this config works):

```
0:  from all lookup local
0:  from 192.168.1.192/26 lookup 200
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

However, after `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

systemd log after restarting systemd-networkd:

```
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: ens192: Gained IPv6LL
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: ens160: Gained IPv6LL
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: Enumeration completed
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: ens160: Link is not managed by us
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: ens192: Configured
Nov 20 17:30:28 lb1 systemd-networkd[1810]: ens160: Configured
```

Update 1: Issuing two `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` applies the rule after the second invocation. One more and it goes away. Wut. Logs show it being applied, not explicitly though, each time:

```
Nov 20 18:57:52 lb1 systemd-networkd[1461]: ens160: Setting routing policy rules
Nov 20 18:57:52 lb1 systemd-networkd[1461]: ens160: Setting routes
Nov 20 18:57:52 lb1 systemd-networkd[1461]: ens160: Routing policy rule configured
Nov 20 18:57:52 lb1 systemd-networkd[1461]: ens160: Routes set
Nov 20 18:57:52 lb1 systemd-networkd[1461]: ens160: Configured
```

Update 2: successive `netplan apply` also toggle the rule in and out.

Comment: please file a bug against systemd-networkd for this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd